# R code for STARFM FUSION using preprocess data from Google Earth Engine

Tags: r, landsat, fusion

I would like to quickly fusion Landsat and Modis data.
I found the code solution at https://github.com/MacGallagher/GEE_STARFM_FUSION
However, when I tried to run the R code in [geestarfm_workflow.R](https://github.com/MacGallagher/GEE_STARFM_FUSION/blob/master/geestarfm_workflow.R)
there are some errors, I recognize that it originates from Line 71 because 
filt3(3) is not a function. And, another error as below:

> Error in .local(.Object, ...) :
>
> Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype =
>   "RasterLayer",  :    Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this
>   file. (file does not exist)

Any solution to solve these issue. I also attach the code and [DATA](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16qGdAASoHmQrkcmml1MKsIksG5X7bc_s?usp=sharing) here:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)
library(fields)

###########################################Inputs##########################################################
## Load images and dates (be careful ofmatching dates and layers, the first layer may repeat)
## Read imagery dates and matching data:
image_dates<- read.csv("./2016_Dates_BOP.csv", stringsAsFactors=F) 
## dates are not used in this code but are useful for other programs like bfastspatial, to check date overlap, and timing

modis<-brick("./2016_mod.tif")
landsat<-brick("./2016_landsat.tif")

##percentage of cover that is used to find "good" landsat scenes for interpolation 
## is the inverse of the actual cloud cover, 99 percent means 1 percent of the pixels is an actual value
perc<- 99

##################################################Code########################################################
#### STARFM code and function
starfm<-function(modis,landsat,perc){
config <- readLines("./StarFM_config.txt")
config <- gsub("(.*NROWS = ).*$", paste0("\\1", nrow(landsat)),config )
config <- gsub("(.*NCOLS = ).*$", paste0("\\1", ncol(landsat)),config )
cat(config, file="./StarFM_config.txt", sep="\n")

## Fix any missing data that enters as zeroes to our NA value.We have
## to do this by layer as operating on the entire stack may run into
## memory issues on larger subsets:
for (i in 1:nlayers(modis)) {
  ## Use the raster Which() function for speed:
  masked <- Which(modis[[i]] == 0, cells=TRUE)
  modis[[ i ]][ masked ] <- -32768
  masked <- Which(landsat[[i]] == 0, cells=TRUE)
  landsat[[ i ]][ masked ] <- -32768
}


## Automatically choose "good" landsat layers, at the moment this includes all actual landsat images
## if you want to create a threshhold for masking change the total percent of the pixel.
## i.e. if percent = 30, more than 70 percent of the image must be actual pixel values


area<-landsat@nrows*landsat@ncols
perc_Area<-(perc/100)*area

test2<-rep(NA,nlayers(modis))
filternew<-rep(NA,nlayers(modis))

for (i in 2:nlayers(modis)){
  test2[i] <-sum(landsat[[i]][]) 
  filternew[i] <-(test2[i]>{-32768*perc_Area}) == 1
}
filt3 = which(filternew==1)
filt3 <-append(filt3,1,0)

## Test landsat image from list

good_layer <- filt3(3)
plot(landsat[[good_layer]])

## If the above all works, then we run the following to loop over the
## MODIS time steps, filling in Landsat output as we go:

landsat_sim <- stack(modis)
landsat_sim[] <- NA

## Iterate and run StarFM for each MODIS date, choosing the
## nearest pair of good MODIS/Landsat dates, one before and
## one after the date being simulated where possible: 

good_landsat <- c(filt3) 
back <- 0 
forward <- 0
pb <- pbCreate((nlayers(landsat_sim)), "window", style=3,label='Time Step Progress')
for (i in 1:nlayers(landsat_sim)) {
  ##for (i in 1:10) {

  ## jakes/megan's work
  rm(back,forward)

  if (i %in% c(filt3)){
    back <- 0
    forward <- 0
    ls_t1temp<- i
    ls_t3temp <- i
  }
  else {
    foo <- good_landsat - i


    if(!length(which(foo==0))){
      back <- good_landsat[which(foo==max(foo[foo < 0]))]
      forward <- good_landsat[which(foo==min(foo[foo > 0]))]
      ls_t1temp <- back
      ls_t3temp <-forward
    }
  }

  ##end
  ls_t1 <- ls_t1temp
  ls_t3 <- ls_t3temp
  m_t1 <- ls_t1
  m_t3 <- ls_t3

  modis_t1 <- modis[[m_t1]]
  modis_t2 <- modis[[i]]
  modis_t3 <- modis[[m_t3]]
  landsat_t1 <- landsat[[ls_t1]]
  landsat_t3 <- landsat[[ls_t3]]


  writeRaster(modis_t1, filename="./modis_t1.envi", bandorder='BSQ', datatype='INT2S', format="ENVI", overwrite=TRUE)

  writeRaster(modis_t2, filename="./modis_t2.envi",bandorder='BSQ', datatype='INT2S', format="ENVI", overwrite=TRUE)

  writeRaster(modis_t3, filename="./modis_t3.envi", bandorder='BSQ', datatype='INT2S', format="ENVI", overwrite=TRUE)
  writeRaster(landsat_t1, filename="./landsat_t1.envi", bandorder='BSQ', datatype='INT2S', format="ENVI", overwrite=TRUE)
  writeRaster(landsat_t3, filename="./landsat_t3.envi", bandorder='BSQ', datatype='INT2S', format="ENVI", overwrite=TRUE)

  system2(command="./StarFM.exe",args="StarFM_config.txt", wait=TRUE)

  landsat_t2_sim <- raster("./landsat_t2_sim.envi")


  ## Set any -32768 to NA values before writing:
  landsat_t2_sim[ landsat_t2_sim == -32768 ] <- NA
  landsat_sim[[i]] <- landsat_t2_sim[]

  ## In our filled data set, set any missing Landsat pixels to those
  ## simulated via StarFM:


    pbStep(pb, step=NULL, label='Processed Layer') }

   pbClose(pb, timer=T)
  return(landsat_sim)
}


landsat_sim<-starfm(modis,landsat,perc)
```

Comment: You should probably flag this as an issue with the author of the code on their github site. To run this code requires a load of files which we don't have.

Comment: Thank for your information,
I did try, but the author upgraded it 2 years ago.
I edited the topic and added the data along, please help me check it.
Thanks

Comment: How did you get past the `Error in filt3(3) : could not find function "filt3"`? Did you do `filt3[3]` instead? Does that make sense?

Comment: I did try and fix this.
Even i figure out the STARFM source https://www.ars.usda.gov/research/software/download/?softwareid=432
But it still has the second error

Comment: Again, **how did you get past the error with filt3(3)**? Did you change it to `filt[3]`? Is that the right thing? Otherwise how are we going to replicate what you did to get the second error?

Comment: I did change filt(3) by filt[3] as suggested before, and passed this error.
However, the other things i think it is originated by the ability to run the processing software namely **StarFM.exe". It seems likely could not run in Window 10 64bit or something. I did check it alone in cmd but it could not run.
Please help me, because I really need it for my research.
Thanks

Comment: Okay this is a *very* different problem - if you can't run the external program in your operating system then you should probably try and fix that. Start a new question and show how you run it from the cmd line and the error message, give all details about where you downloaded it, version number, OS detail etc.